# unable to uninstall comodo on 12.04 lts 32-bit system

Tags: 12.04

I tried to uninstall comodo but it is showing the following errors:

```
anurag@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get --purge remove cav-linux
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
anurag@ubuntu:~$
```

What can I do about this?

Answer (score -1):

Step #1 = Boot an Ubuntu disc, and choose try without installing

Step #2 = open nautilus and open your ubuntu install, thus mounting it.

Step #3 = Open terminal and type:

"sudo mount --bind /dev /#location#/dev"

"sudo mount --bind /proc /#location#/proc"

"sudo mount --bind /sys /#location#/sys"

"sudo chroot /#location#" (don't close the terminal or you'll have to type this again)

"apt-get --purge remove cav-linux"

Step # 4 = shutdown the live cd and reboot into your Ubuntu 12.04 install.

[#location# equates to the mounted access for your ubuntu install, eg /media/ubuntu/sda1 ]